# Using apply method on pandas series getting TypeError 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames `D1` and `D2`. What I want to achieve is for any column pairs in `D1` and `D2` which are non-int and non-float type, I want to compute a distance metric using the formula

```
 |A intersect B|/ |A union B|
```

I first defined a function

```
def jaccard_d(series1, series2):
    if (series1.dtype is not (pd.np.dtype(int) or pd.np.dtype(float))) and     (series2.dtype is not (pd.np.dtype(int) or pd.np.dtype(float))):
        series1 = series1.drop_duplicates()
        series2 = series2.drop_duplicates()
        return len(set(series1).intersection(set(series2)))     /len(set(series1).union(set(series2)))
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Then what I did is to first loop over all columns in `D1`, then for each fixed column in `D1`, I use `apply` on my `jaccard_d` function. I try to avoid writing 2 layer loops. May be there is a better way without wrting any loops?

```
DC = dict.fromkeys(list(D1.columns))
INN = list(D2.columns)
for col in D1:
    DC[col] = dict(zip(INN, D2.apply(jaccard_d,D1[col])))
```

First, I am not sure whether I use the `apply` function correctly, i.e., my `jaccard_d` function takes 2 series as input, but here for each iteration, I have `D1[col]` as one series, and I want to use `apply` to apply `D1[col]` to all columns of `D2`

Second, I get this error "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", which I don't quite understand. Any comments are appreciated.

I tried to just write a 2-layer loop and use my function `jaccard_d` to do that. It works. But I want to write more efficient code.

Comment: You are trying to use a pandas `series` as a dictionary key.

Comment: @hpaulj could you please elaborate a little bit? And how to fix that? Why if I just write a 2-layer loop this will not be a problem?

Comment: This may be a minor point, but do you need `drop_dupicates` if you are already putting the series into `set`?  `set` collects unique values anyways.

Comment: The problem is in how you pass the data series  to `apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after floundering around, and finding exactly where the error occurs, and checking the `apply` docs, I've deduced that you need to call `apply` thusly:

```
 D2.apply(jaccard_d, args=(D1[col],))
```

Instead you were using

```
 D2.apply(jaccard_d, axis=D1[col])
```

==================

I can reproduce your error message with a simple dataframe:

```
In [589]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(6,2))
In [590]: df
Out[590]: 
    0   1
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   6   7
4   8   9
5  10  11
```

Putting a Series in `set` works, just as if we'd put a list in `set`:

```
In [591]: set(df[0]).union(set(df[1]))
Out[591]: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

But if I try to put a list containing a Series in the set I get your error.

```
In [592]: set([df[0]])
....
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

If the problem isn't with the the `set` expressions then it occurs in the `dict()` one.

You did not specify where the error occurs, nor have you given a MVCe.

(but as it turns out this is a deadend)

========================

OK, simulating your code:

```
In [606]: DC=dict.fromkeys(list(df.columns))
In [607]: DC
Out[607]: {0: None, 1: None}
In [608]: INN=list(df.columns)
In [609]: INN
Out[609]: [0, 1]
In [610]: for col in df:
     ...:     dict(zip(INN, df.apply(jaccard_d, df[col])))
    ....
----> 2     dict(zip(INN, df.apply(jaccard_d, df[col])))


/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   ...
-> 4125         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_axis_number(self, axis)
    326 
    327     def _get_axis_number(self, axis):
--> 328         axis = self._AXIS_ALIASES.get(axis, axis)
    ....        

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

So the problem is in

```
df.apply(jaccard_d, df[0])
```

The problem has nothing to do with `jaccard_d`.  It occurs if I replace it with simple

```
def foo(series1, series2):
    print(series1)
    print(series2)
    return 1
```

======================

But look at the docs for `apply`

```
df.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)
```

The 2nd argument, if not keyword, is the axis number.  So we have been trying to use a Series as the axis number!  No wonder it objects!   That should have been obvious if I'd read the error trace more carefully.

Leaving the default `axis=0`, lets pass the other Series as `args`:

```
In [632]: df.apply(jaccard_d,args=(df[1],))
Out[632]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
dtype: float64
```

or in your loop:

```
In [643]: for col in df:
     ...:     DC[col] = dict(zip(INN, df.apply(jaccard_d,args=(df[col],))))  
In [644]: DC
Out[644]: {0: {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0}, 1: {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0}}
```